# Making an image an upload function without making it an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm in a sticky situation. I'm trying to make an image an upload button, but I cannot change that image at all... however, when you click the image, I have it calling a JS function I can put anything into.

How can I launch an browser upload though this function alone? Normally I would just make the image an input, but like I said, in this case I cannot do that.

Does anyone have an example they could share?

Here's my function (which is called onclick of the image):

```
 function fnImport(elem){
    var $input;

    $input = $input || $("<input type='file'>");
    $('#Import').append($input);
    $input.click();
    $input.hide();



    }
```

However, when I run it, on the first click it adds the button, then on second it acts as an upload (and doesn't hide in either).

In addition, I'm getting a strange  as well in my console?

Comment: you can't just launch an upload just by calling something. That is a matter of security. If it would be possible a website could automatically upload data from the user machine without the knowledge of the user

Comment: By launching an upload, I may have not been clear. I mean, I just want the computer file browser to appear, as if they clicked on "<input type="file">, not an automatic upload of something on their computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might spark some ideas for you: http://jsfiddle.net/NKekN/2/

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly on the lines I was thinking. However, I'm having trouble placing it inside my pre-existing click function. I've updated my question with some code (and added a hide to the input field you added!) -- could you help me sort this out by chance?

Comment: Works perfect -- was having trouble fitting into my code for a second. Thank you for your help!